# previous button for easy_jquery_auto_image_rotator

Tags: jquery, image, rotation

I am using this simple image rotator, but I want to add a previous button. I have figured out the 'next' button, but am having trouble with going back. Here is the code: [view code](http://www.alohatechsupport.net/webdesignmaui/maui-web-site-design/easy_jquery_auto_image_rotator.html)

For a next button I just called 'rotate();' but I can't figure how to modify it to go the other way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the function rotate() I managed another rotate2(). pay attention on the function end: new time interval . full solution: http://jsfiddle.net/wt6nc0uz/1/

```
function rotate2() {    
    //Get the first image
    var current = ($('div.rotator ul li.show')? $('div.rotator ul li.show') : $('div.rotator ul li:first'));

    if ( current.length == 0 ) current = $('div.rotator ul li:first');

    //Get next image, when it reaches the end, rotate it back to the first image
    var prev = ((current.prev().length) ? ((current.prev().hasClass('show')) ? $('div.rotator ul li:last') :current.prev()) : $('div.rotator ul li:last'));


    //Set the fade in effect for the next image, the show class has higher z-index
    prev.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('show').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

    //Hide the current image
    clearInterval(interval);
    current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000, function(){interval=setInterval('rotate2()', 6000);}) .removeClass('show');

};
```